# Type Hint: same variable length tuples for input and output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a function as follow:

```py
from typing import Tuple

def add_one(numbers: Tuple[int, ...]) -> Tuple[int, ...]:
    return tuple(number+1 for number in numbers)
```

This function takes a Tuple of variable length as an input, and returns another Tuple with the same length.

My questions is: how can I express this with type hints ?
As you can see in my example, I was only able to express that both input and output tuples had variable length, not that they have the same.

*Edit: this is a dummy example that I used to explain what I meant, while I wouldn't implement it this way IRL, I got a much more complex function that would justify the need for this kind of type hint*

Comment: are type hints the way to go here? why not add a programmatic check of `len()` in the function?

Comment: I think this is still [under investigation](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3345).

Comment: @Chris_Rands because I know for sure that the input and output are the same length, I just want my editor to know it too

Comment: @chepner indeed! I didn't think I'd reach the limit of type hinting so soon, well I just need to wait I guess. thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TypeVar`:

```py
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar

TupleType = TypeVar("TupleType", bound=Tuple[int, ...])

def add_one(numbers: TupleType) -> TupleType:
    return tuple(number+1 for number in numbers) # type: ignore[return-value]
    
a = add_one((1, 2, 3))
reveal_type(a)
```

It shows:

```
Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.int, builtins.int, builtins.int]
```